# How to "throw" a Bad Request from a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, http-status-code-400

I have a very simple JSP file, which more or less displays a get variable.

```
<p>Hello, <%= request.getParameter("name") %></p>
```

So, if I go to `webpage.jsp?name=Alice`, I'd get `Hello, Alice`. If I just go to `webpage.jsp` on the other hand, I get `Hello, null`.

If the name variable is not set, I would like to send a Bad Request instead. In a servlet I'd do this:

```
  response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
  return;
```

How can I do similarly from a JSP page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the same code inside `<% %>` in JSP. You only need to ensure that the response isn't committed at that point, otherwise you would only face `IllegalStateException`s. So it should preferably be invoked on the very top of the JSP file, before all that HTML template content is emitted.

Needless to say, a JSP is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) the right place to control the request/response. In this particular case, you'd like to do the job in a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) or perhaps a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) if it concerns a session wide login. Further, that "Hello" line is better to be done as `<p>Hello, <c:out value="${param.name}" /></p>`. It not only improves maintainability, but it also prevents your site from a huge XSS attack hole.

Comment: Couldn't get the c:out stuff to work, but changed it to `<%= StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(request.getParameter("cid")) %>`, which hopefully does the job as well :)

Comment: Just install JSTL (if your container doesn't support it) and declare `c` taglib. For installation and declaration details see also our JSTL wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info (I hope you noticed the Servlet and Filter wiki page links in my answer as well?)